# Як перекласти англійське слово squatter?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Як перекласти англійське слово squatter (у значенні *"той, хто незаконно оселився у будинку/території/землі"*) одним словом? На сайті словотвора я цього слова не знайшов. Звичайні друковані словники дають переклад-тлумачення з майже десяти слів, але не надають варіанту перекладу одним словом.

Бажано: якщо ваш пропонований переклад — неологізм/новотвір, то було б гарно, якби нове слово було утворене з питомо українського кореня. Щось на зразок *припертюх* (від дієслова *припертися*).

Comment: _Понаїхало_ (іменник, чол. рід), _заїздисько_ (так само), _сíдок_.

Comment: До речі, [Словотвір](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/skvoter) пропонує «безхатько». Хоча це трішки інше значення, по-моєму (хіба що «чужохатько»). Іще: «самопоселенець»; [вживається](//www.google.com/search?q=самопоселенець) (книжки: [1](//books.google.com/books?id=TUlGAQAAIAAJ&q=самопоселенець), [2](http://www.inmo.org.ua/assets/files/Taranenko.%20Aktualizovani%20modeli%20(2015).pdf); наприклад щодо Чорнобиля); по-моєму, це саме те.

Comment: Стаття у вікіпедії [Самосели зони відчуження](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F). У статті ще декілька посилань на газетні статті із "самоселами".

Comment: @Sasha @ Artemix @ YellowSky Як щодо перенесення вашого коментаря у відповіді? Обидва ваші пропоновані варіанти - реально гарні!

Comment: @Yola Якби ми зараз жили у 16-18 сторіччі то такий би новотвір був би дуже вдалим. Але у поточному сторіччі та враховуючи що українці + кримські татари це два  корінні народи території України, такий неологізм був би політично некоректним. Я, до речі, pc bro й намагаюсь використовувати політично коректну термінологію

Comment: Значення слова squatter не гарантує того, що зайняте місце зайняте незаконно. Його багато стали використовувати для тих, людей, які займають якесь певне місце без дозволу, але по суті означає людину, що сидить накарачки (наче гопник))) ). Тобто коли багато ходив та дуже стомився і щоб відпочили ноги присів тимчасово.

Answer (score 6):

Монографія О. О. Тараненка "АКТУАЛІЗОВАНІ МОДЕЛІ В СИСТЕМІ СЛОВОТВОРЕННЯ
СУЧАСНОЇ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ" 2015 (НАНУ, Інститут мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні) дає два варіанти ([pdf](http://www.inmo.org.ua/assets/files/Taranenko.%20Aktualizovani%20modeli%20(2015).pdf)):

- **самопоселе́нець**, ж. **самопоселе́нка**;
- *розмовне* **самосе́л**.

які вживаються щодо жителів Чорнобильської зони та кримських татар, що поверталися у Крим:

> ...Утворення з нейтральною або більш чи менш
> несхвальною конотаціями: **самопоселенець**, ж. **самопоселенка**,
> розм. **самосел** (звичайно про жителів сіл у межах Чорнобильської
> 30-кілометрової зони, відселених після аварії 1986 р., які згодом
> з власної ініціативи стали повертатися на рідні місця; про кримських татар, які з кінця 80-х рр. стали повертатися на свою історичну батьківщину й займати без дозволу органів місцевої влади
> земельні ділянки): *«Чому нас учить поведінка так званих самоселів — чорнобильців, котрі не змогли жити в степах, куди їх відселили, й повернулися до свого краю, хай небезпечного, але рідного?»* (Н. Околітенко. — ЛУ, 28.04.1994, с. 5);

---

Слово "самосел" вживається також у білоруській та російській мові.

Стаття у Вікіпедії [Самосели зони відчуження](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F). У статті ще декілька посилань на газетні статті із "самоселами".

Стаття стверджує що слово у статтях журналістів з'явилося ще з 80-х років.

Для української мови я знайшов лише у ВТССУМ 2005 року з приміткою "розмовне" ([Lingvo](http://www.lingvo.ua/ru/Interpret/uk-uk/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB), [academic](http://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/160228/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)):

> **самосе́л**
> -а, ч., розм.
> Той, хто самовільно заселяється куди-небудь.

Білоруською знайшовся (**самосёл**) у книзі письменника Василя Бикова "Вовча яма" 1998 року ("[Васіль Быкаў. Ваўчыная яма](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F1%E0%EC%EE%F1%E5%EB&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&mode=para)") теж про Чорнобильску зону.

Російською можна знайти переклад книги Бикова на російську мову (1999 рік) та [газетні статті](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F1%E0%EC%EE%F1%E5%EB&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&mode=paper) про чорнобильскіх "самоселів" після 2001 року.

Але, з огляду на згадані у Вікіпедії статті 80-х, схоже що більшість прикладів вжитку є лише у офлайн-виданнях.

---

Стаття "Самосели зони відчуження" цитує Ліну Костенко, яка вказує що така назва ("самосели") є образливою для поселенців (а отже несе негативну конотацію, так само як і слово squatter):

> Самоселами цих людей почали називати журналісти ще з 80-х років 20-го століття. Вчені, учасники історико-етнографічних експедицій у зону відчуження, серед яких і поетеса Ліна Костенко, вважають таку назву некоректною:
>
> > Я відразу хотіла б попросити, щоб тих людей ніхто не називав самоселами: це образливо, адже там їхня батьківщина. Вони виросли там і продовжують жити після аварії у своїх рідних будинках – хай і забуті Богом і державою.

Comment: Звернула увагу, що коли йдеться про самоселів Чорнобильської зони чи кримських татар-самоверненців, то це люди, які повертаються на _свою_ територію, куди з різних причин їм заборонено повертатись. Тоді як **[сквотер](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сквот)** — особа, що займає _чуже_ помешкання без згоди власника, і це слово несе негативну конотацію.

Comment: @ata_zh Ліна Костенко вбачає у слові "самосел" негативну конотацію (з Вікіпедії): Самоселами цих людей почали називати журналісти ще з 80-х років 20-го століття. Вчені, учасники історико-етнографічних експедицій у зону відчуження, серед яких і поетеса Ліна Костенко, вважають таку назву некоректною: "Я відразу хотіла б попросити, щоб тих людей ніхто не називав самоселами: це образливо, адже там їхня батьківщина. Вони виросли там і продовжують жити після аварії у своїх рідних будинках – хай і забуті Богом і державою".

Answer (score 2):

**Татарин**

На цю думку мене навели прислів'я і події повернення кримських татар на історичну батьківщину - Крим.

Прислів'я: Непрошений гість - гірше татарина.

Події в Криму:

- [У Криму вперше добровільно звільняють самозахват](https://www.unian.ua/society/517743-u-krimu-vpershe-dobrovilno-zvilnyayut-samozahvat.html)
- [Коли ми це зробимо, Крим сам повернеться](https://life.pravda.com.ua/columns/2016/01/27/207215/)

Хоча самі кримські татари називають це не самозахоплення, а самоповернення.

---

Чому цей варіант непрохідний:

1. Політично некоректний
2. Перевантажує слово *татарин*, краще вигадати нове.

Comment: Arguably, прислів'я [прийшло](http://frazbook.ru/2008/12/21/nezvanyj-gost-xuzhe-tatarina/#comment-263) з Московського царства, де словом *татарин* називали збирача податку, який Москва платила Сараю. А у якості етноніму використовувалося слово *булгарин* або *каза́нець*. Більше ранній вжиток слова «татарин» означав «жителів **країни на Півночі Китаю**» ([Фасмер](http://www.endic.ru/fasmer/Tatarin-13382.html)). Тому запропонований варіант не лише неправильний і чужорідний, а ще й вводить в оману. «Збирач податку» — це зовсім не те само, що «той, хто вчинив самовільне захоплення території».

Answer (score 1):

[Займанець](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C) -

> Той, хто першим зайняв вільну (незайману) землю.

Comment: "[Займанщина](http://sum.in.ua/s/zajmanshhyna) - Земельна власність, придбана правом першого зайняття вільної землі".  - тобто є хтось (громада, закон) хто визнає таке право. Але сквоттер займає територію без такого права. Чи не так?

Comment: @Artemix По-перше, питання не про займанщину, а про людину, яка займає. По-друге, squatter - не вказує на законність чи незаконність. Це слово вказує на те, що щось зайняли. Тобто побачив місце, прийшов до нього, сів накарачки і нікуди не йдеш. Ось тоді ти стаєш займанцем. Або накарачником, якщо хочете, приблизно це означає слово squatter дослівно.